# css for a tag but not a tag that contain image

Tags: html, css

i am apply hover effect on `a` tag just want to know is this possible to apply css only those a tag that will not have an image inside

```
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#"><img src='abc.png'></a>

a:hover,a:focus,.text-link:hover,.text-link:focus{
    background: #551011;
    color: #8b6508;
}
```

this is what i tried but not working

```
a:not(img):hover,a:not(img):focus,.text-link:not(img):hover,.text-link:not(img):focus{
    background: #551011;
    color: #8b6508;
}
```

what i am doing wrong

Comment: Give your text link the `text-link` class and delete the global a:hover/a:focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
  a:not(.myimage):hover,a:not(.myimage):focus,.text-link:not(.myimage):hover,.text-link:not(.myimage):focus{
    background: #551011;
    color: #8b6508;
}
</style>
      </head>

    <body>
     <a href="#">link</a>
<a class="myimage"  href="#"><img src='abc.png'></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this any possible way to do this without image class

Answer (score 0):

Do not us the global style

a:hover, a:focus {}

This affects all the a-tags. on your site.
Use a scope or a class ... Like you `text-link` class.
Delete the rest.

```css
.text-link:hover,.text-link:focus{
    background: #551011;
    color: #8b6508;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class='text-link'>link</a>
<a href="#"><img src='http://files.dlink.com.au/website_images/baby_cam/gettingstarted_images/ABC_4.png' width="180px"></a>
```